# previous extension giving 404 on installing new module in magento2

Tags: magento2, 404

I have created a stripe module that allow to create standard account from customer section, was working fine, but as I installed new webkul's stripe checkout module, my module giving 404 error.

Any suggestion ? How to resolve this ?

Comment: Have you checked front name of both extension ?

Comment: Frontname is different but 'id' is same  `<route id="stripe" frontName="stripe">`,  '<route id="stripe" frontName="netzstripe">'

Comment: I have changed the  route id of my extension to  '<route id="netzstripeid" frontName="netzstripe">' , now its not giving 404 but content part is not loading .........

Answer (score 0):

route-id of my module and webkul's modules were same (i.e 'stripe') thats why its giving 404 error. I change the route id to 'abcroute' then 404 error gone but content not loading, So also made changes in respective layout file name from 'stripe_index_index.xml' to 'abcroute_index_index.xml'.

Now all working fine...

Thanks @yogesh to give hints.....

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that there could be a conflict between your custom Stripe module and the new Webkul's Stripe checkout module. Here are a few things you can try to resolve the issue:

- Check for any conflicting code or files between the two modules. Make sure that there are no files or functions that are overlapping or conflicting with each other.
- Disable the Webkul's Stripe checkout module temporarily to see if your custom module is working without any issues. If it's working, then the problem might be with the new module.
- Check the error logs to see if there are any specific error messages that can help identify the issue.
- Contact the support team of both modules to see if they can help identify and resolve the issue.
- Consider integrating your custom Stripe module with the Webkul's Stripe checkout module to avoid conflicts and ensure compatibility.

By trying these steps, you should be able to identify and resolve the issue with your custom Stripe module.